# Use Event Handler's code inside my own code

Tags: c#, event-handling

```
private void OnCarSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Car tmpCar = (Car)CarLST.SelectedItem;
        VinNumberTB.Text = tmpCar.VinNumber;
        CarMakeTB.Text = tmpCar.CarMake;
        CarTypeCB.SelectedIndex = (int)tmpCar.Type;
        PurchasePriceTB.Text = tmpCar.PurchasePrice.ToString();
        ModelYearCB.SelectedItem = tmpCar.ModelYear;
        MileageTB.Text = tmpCar.Mileage.ToString();
        CarIMG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(String.Format("ms-appx:///Assets/CarImages/{0}.png", tmpCar.Type.ToString())));
    }
```

This corresponds to a list box's selectionChanged event handler. Is there a way I can just use this in my code as if it were a method. e.g.
`SelectionChanged(foo, bar);`
Basically, is there a way of using this block of code again without creating another method to hold this stuff.

Comment: Heads up: pictures of code usually attract downvotes.  Paste it as text.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. New guy here please be gentle.

Comment: Best way is to create a new method with the code.  Then call new method from OnCarSecelctionChanged (remove existing code) so you can execute code from the event and from other places in your code.

Comment: have you _tried_ using it as a method? the only thing that could actually trouble you there is the `private` access modifier

Comment: You could call it as `OnCarSelectionChanged(null, null)`, as it seems you don't need the params. But is much cleaner and clearer to read if you create a function you call whenever you want t..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't use any of the event arguments, you can extract the code into a separate method:

```
private void OnCarSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateDisplay();
}


private void UpdateDisplay()
{
    Car tmpCar = (Car)CarLST.SelectedItem;
    VinNumberTB.Text = tmpCar.VinNumber;
    CarMakeTB.Text = tmpCar.CarMake;
    CarTypeCB.SelectedIndex = (int)tmpCar.Type;
    PurchasePriceTB.Text = tmpCar.PurchasePrice.ToString();
    ModelYearCB.SelectedItem = tmpCar.ModelYear;
    MileageTB.Text = tmpCar.Mileage.ToString();
    CarIMG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(String.Format("ms-appx:///Assets/CarImages/{0}.png", tmpCar.Type.ToString())));
}
```

Then to call it separately all you need to do is:

```
this.UpdateDisplay();
```